# MongoDB - Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal, drupal-7

For the past 2 hours I am trying to find the solution to my error. I am trying to retrive the entries from a specific table, but it always saying

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   web_performance/models/MongoDbConnection.php on line 18

Any suggestions what to do ?

This is my db connection class

```
class MongoDbConnection {
    private $_mongoDb=null;
    private $_table;


    public function __constructor($dbAddress='localhost') {
        $this->_mongoDb=new Mongo($dbAddress);
    }

    public function setTable($argTableName){
        $this->_table=$this->_mongoDb->$argTableName;
        return $this;
    } 

    //select method
    public function find(){
        $this->_table->find(); // <- Line 18
        return $this;
    }

    //create insert method
    /*public function insert($values){
        $this->_table->insert($values);
        return $this;
    }*/

    //update method
    public function update($values){
        $this->_table->update($values);
        return $this;
    }

    //delete method
    public function dbMongoDelete($values){
        throw new Exception('Delete not yet defined in '.__CLASS__);            
    }

//end class 
}
```

This is my Settings Class

```
module_load_include('php', 'web_performance', 'models/MongoDbConnection');

class BenchmarkingSettings {
    private $_mongoDb;
    static private $_instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_mongoDb=new MongoDbConnection();    
    }

    static public function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance=new BenchmarkingSettings();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function populateFormWithValueSettings(){
        $response=$this->_mongoDb->setTable("benchmarkingSettings")->find();

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
public function __constructor($dbAddress='localhost') {
```

to

```
public function __construct($dbAddress='localhost') {
```

Comment: Yup, I believe the "parent" class has no connection, and therefore $this->_mongoDb->$argTableName is just a string.

Comment: yes, that was the issue, I can't believe it, but now is returning me that the connection is close.